# ForceType text/html;charset=utf-8 in .htaccess is causing all externally linked CSS to stop rendering

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm using:

`ForceType text/html;charset=utf-8`

in my .htaccess file, but it's causing all externally linked CSS to stop rendering on their respective pages.

So something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="somestyles.css" media="all" />
```

no longer works on the page using it.

I've also been trying combinations of:

```
AddCharset utf-8 .html
AddCharset utf-8 .htm
AddCharset utf-8 .css
AddCharset utf-8 .js
ForceType text/html;charset=utf-8
ForceType text/css;charset=utf-8
```

but no luck so far.  Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: for me, this worked! : https://stackoverflow.com/a/76260449/10079059

Answer (score 7):

This is all you need to get UTF-8 for both CSS and Javascript files:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
AddCharset utf-8 .css .js
```

Comment: Don't assume mod_mime is enabled. (I did) Debian doesn't enable it by default. Wrap these in a <IfModule mod_mime.c> </IfModule> just to be sure.

Answer (score 5):

This works for me on my web host (in my root .htaccess):

```
#for html, php
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
#for css, js
AddType 'text/css; charset=UTF-8' css
AddType 'application/x-javascript; charset=UTF-8' js
```

I'm not sure, but I think the ForceType may be telling the browser that the css file is html, not css.

**UPDATE:**

First of all, `application/x-javascript` should not be used anymore; it should be `application/javascript` (`x-` meant experimental).  But it's even simpler than that, at least for Apache 2.2.22

```
#for html, php
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
#for css, js, etc.
AddCharset UTF-8 .js .css
```

Using `AddType` also sets the MIME type, which Apache is likely to take care of correctly, while my original answer set it *incorrectly* for javascript (as of today).  So let Apache do its job on MIME types and use the shorter and simpler single-line `AddCharset` for all additional types.