# htaccess UTF-8 encoding for .html, .css, .js - Whats the best way?

Tags: .htaccess, utf-8, pagespeed, yslow

For yslow page speed I want to remove my meta tag and put my encoding into the .htaccess file. Below are all the ways to do it I have read about. Which is the preferred way? Also is the language setting a good idea too - and if out side of the filesmatch will it apply to all file types?

1) https://github.com/jancbeck/My-Wordpress-Boilerplate/blob/master/htaccess.txt

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
AddCharset utf-8 .html .css .js
DefaultLanguage en-US
```

vs

2) http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/using-http-headers-with-htaccess.html

```
<filesMatch "\.(html|css|js)$">
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
DefaultLanguage en-US
</filesMatch>
```

vs

3) I suspect this is all that's needed. But untested.

```
AddCharset UTF-8 .html .css .js
DefaultLanguage en-US
```

Answer (score 32):

I think

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

is enough for all.

Maybe better way is set encoding to files, which are using different charset than default.

Comment: Reading more I see a few respected sites saying... AddDefaultCharset UTF-8 will serve all files regardless of file extension. Time to test I guess

Comment: @Eric I am using that, never the less, the lack of a charset is detected on my css and js files on 3rd party tools.

Comment: Adding this to an xml file didn't used the utf-8. Adding `AddCharset UTF-8 .xml` did. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/913884/1057527).

Comment: The [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#adddefaultcharset) says "This directive specifies a default value for the media type charset parameter (the name of a character encoding) to be added to a response **if and only if the response's content-type is either text/plain or text/html**". So this is NOT enough for all.

Comment: Where in my .htaccess do I need to place it? Should it go at the top, bottom or below something else?

Comment: @RichardYoung Unless there is another AddDefaultCharset directive in the .htaccess file, it does not matter.  I personally place mine at the top first, with a explanatory comment #explaining why it's used.  For urgent fixes placing at the bottom might work better, as there may be another AddDefaultCharset directive, and Apache will honor the last usage of a directive.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was for Persian(فارسی) text in js files which was showing like (Ø¹Ø¨Ø§Ø±Øª)

I added the code below in **.htaccess** file, and my problem was solved! :

```
<filesMatch "\.(html|js)$">
     Header set Content-Type "text/x-java-source; charset=UTF-8"
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "^[Mm]akefile$">
     Header set Content-Type "text/plain; charset=UTF-8"
</FilesMatch>
```

for me `AddCharset UTF-8 .js` and `AddDefaultCharset utf-8` didn't help