# Arabic text not display but charactere Ø§Ù„Ù…Ù…Ù„Ùƒ display

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display arabic text but charactere Ø§Ù„Ù…Ù…Ù„Ùƒ display.

For example the word المملكة العربية السعودية  display on  Ø§Ù„Ù…Ù…Ù„ÙƒØ© Ø§Ù„Ø¹Ø±Ø¨ÙŠØ© Ø§Ù„Ø³Ø¹ÙˆØ¯ÙŠØ©

I add on my page always encoded on UTF-8:

```
 <meta charset="utf-8">
```

but that not changed.

Have you a idea about that?

Thank you.

Comment: How is your html file saved/what is real encoding of supplied string?

Comment: Does your computer has fonts of arabic text ?

Comment: try this  https://stackoverflow.com/a/76260449/10079059

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load the text file in a text editor that allows character encoding to be defined, change the character encoding to UTF-8 or unicode and save the file again.

This will pre-prend magic bytes to the file, like `0xFEFF` and the browser will load it accordingly.

This is an excellent explanation: [UTF-8 vs. Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643694/utf-8-vs-unicode)

Comment: I edit with notepad++ and eclipse editor the character is encoded to UTF-8.

Comment: Good, then how exactly do you produce that text? Is it static HTML? a JS string? Downloaded through AJAX? Taken from a DB with C#, PHP, Java? Please be more specific and add code examples, because right now it's impossible to understand where the problem is.

Comment: It's a static text html and javascript

Answer (score 3):

well, I faced this issue before. I fixed it by converting the types of encoding.
first: does your text comes from Data Base? or its inside your page like HTML tags?

if your text comes from Database please use this:

```
System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(stream, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("WIndows-1252"));
writer.Write("**#your text from database#**");
writer.Flush();
stream.Position = 0;
System.IO.StreamReader xx = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
string converted = xx.ReadToEnd();
```

and if your text inside your page:

just do *save as* and select UTF-8 encoding

thanks