# Can I make browsers choose UTF-8 for viewing source code?

Tags: html, http, character-encoding

I put up some source code files for viewing on the web. The problem is, browsers tend to not understand that these files are in UTF-8, and I wonder if there's anything I can do about that. (I'm sure some browsers use UTF-8 per default, but Safari at least doesn't. I have to go into the *View* menu and choose the encoding manually to make it look right.)

My set of webpages is here, with several Python files and one C file: [fgcode.avadeaux.net](https://fgcode.avadeaux.net/). I tried putting a `charset="UTF-8"` attribute in the `a` elements in the , but that doesn't seem to help. The Python files declare the charset in a comment on the top line, but the browser ignores that as well (which is no surprise, it's not a Python source code browser after all).

I don't have much control over the web server, it's run by my ISP and I just put the files there. But I'd still be interested to know if this problem has a web server configuration solution.

**Solution**: solved, as per links provided, by adding an `.htaccess` file with the following content:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
AddCharset UTF-8 .py
AddCharset UTF-8 .c
```

Only the first line wasn't enough in my case.

Comment: This is not a html question, and should not be closed as a duplicate... It's about content delivery headers for non-html files...

Comment: @Slawomir Arguably, but the [duplicate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/423752/476) lays it out quite perfectly.

Comment: @deceze♦ As far as I can see, the “duplicate answer” answers a different question (which I already knew the answer for). The links in @Slawomir's answer are more relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are allowed to place a .htaccess file in your content directory, you might be able to specify a charset there.

YMMV depending on which server software they run, and how permissive the config is.

See:

[How to change the default encoding to UTF-8 for Apache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913869/how-to-change-the-default-encoding-to-utf-8-for-apache)

[htaccess UTF-8 encoding for .html, .css, .js - Whats the best way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13380206/htaccess-utf-8-encoding-for-html-css-js-whats-the-best-way)

Comment: Thanks, didn't help in this case, but good to know that it might in some other cases.

Comment: Strangely enough, my ISP says it can be done this way! <https://help.one.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005594145> But it doesn't seem to work. Anyway, it's pretty clear that it's supposed to be the answer.

Comment: Seems the solution was to add a couple of more lines in .htaccess, see my edited post.

Comment: good to hear it worked :)

Answer (score -2):

You need a `<head>` element in the document being served. In `<head>` you will also need: `<meta charset="utf-8">`.

If the document you're linking to does not have this, you may need to set up a proxy to wrap it. Browsers understand HTML. Your **.py** files are just text, so they contain not instructions the browser will understand.

Comment: Content encoding can *and should* be declared in HTTP headers, not solely in HTML.